# How to repost a webpage?

Tags: perl, cgi

I am creating a simple perl script to create a web page to register users.  This is just a learning program for me.   It is very simple.  I will display a page on the browser.  The user enters name, user name, and password.  After the user presses submit, I will check the user name against the database.  If the user name exists in the database, I just want to display an error and bring up the register page again.  I am using the cgi->redirect function.  I am not sure if that is how I should use the redirection function.  It does not work like I thought.  It display "The document has moved here".  Please point me to the right way.  Thanks.

Here is the scripts

registeruser.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

print <<PAGE;
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tracker.css"/>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <h1> Register New User</h1>
      </div>

      <div id="content">
         <form action="adduser.pl" method="POST">
         <b>Name:</b> <input type="text" name="name"><br>
         <b>UserName:</b> <input type="text" name="username"><br>
         <b>Password:</b> <input type="password" name="password"><br>
         <input type="submit">
      </div>
   </body>
<html>
PAGE
```

adduser.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;
use DBI;

$cgiObj = CGI->new;
print $cgiObj->header ('text/html');

# get post data
$newUser = $cgiObj->param('username');
$newName = $cgiObj->param('name');
$newPass = $cgiObj->param('password');

# set up sql connection
$param = 'DBI:mysql:Tracker:localhost';
$user = 'madison';
$pass = 'qwerty';

$connect = DBI->connect ($param, $user, $pass);

$sql = 'select user from users where user = "' . $newUser . '"';

$query = $connect->prepare ($sql);
$query->execute;

$found = 0;
while (@row = $query->fetchrow_array)
{
   $found = 1;
}

if ($found == 0)
{
   # no user found add new user
   $sql = 'insert into users (user, name, passwd) values (?, ?, ?)';
   $insert = $connect->prepare ($sql);
   $insert->execute ($newUser, $newName, $newPass);
}
else
{
   # user already exists, get new user name
   # What do I do here ????
   print $cgiObj->redirect ("registerusr.pl");
}
```

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your Perl scripts. It will save you many headaches in the long run.

Comment: Ok, I found out what I did wrong.  The print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; was causing the script not to be redirected.

Comment: CGI is dead, and you've opened up a security flaw here. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to look out for, [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). For an illustrated example, [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

As it stands your code is inescure, and can allow people to do bad things to your database. DBI provides placeholders as a secure way of querying a database with user input. Example http://bobby-tables.com/perl.html

Also, in this day and age even the [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI.pm-4.03/lib/CGI.pm#CGI.pm_HAS_BEEN_REMOVED_FROM_THE_PERL_CORE) module warns you not to use it:

> The rational for this decision is that CGI.pm is no longer considered good practice for developing web applications, including quick prototyping and small web scripts. There are far better, cleaner, quicker, easier, safer, more scalable, more extensible, more modern alternatives available at this point in time. These will be documented with [CGI::Alternatives](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-Alternatives-0.11/lib/CGI/Alternatives.pm).

I suggest you use [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Three things

1. Include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.  No exceptions.

   This is the #1 thing that you can do to be a better perl programmer.  It will save you an incalculable amount of time during both development and testing.
2. Don't use redirects to switch between form processing and form display

   Keep your form display and form processing in the same script.  This enables you to display error messages in the form and only move on to a new step upon a successfully processed form.

   You simply need to test the `request_method` to determine if the form is needing to be processed or just displayed.
3. [`CGI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI) works for learning perl, but look at [`CGI::Alternatives`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) for live code.

The following is your form refactored with the first 2 guidelines in mind:

register.pl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;

my $name     = $q->param('name')     // '';
my $username = $q->param('username') // '';
my $password = $q->param('password') // '';

# Process Form
my @errors;
if ( $q->request_method() eq 'POST' ) {
    if ( $username =~ /^\s*$/ ) {
        push @errors, "No username specified.";
    }

    if ( $password =~ /^\s*$/ ) {
        push @errors, "No password specified.";
    }

    # Successful Processing
    if ( !@errors ) {
        # Obfuscate for display
        $password =~ s/./*/g;

        print $q->header();
        print <<"END_PAGE";
<html>
<head><title>Success</title></head>
<body>
<p>Name = $name</p>
<p>Username = $username</p>
<p>Password = $password</p>
</body>
</html>
END_PAGE

        exit;
    }
}

# Display Form

print $q->header();

print <<"END_PAGE";
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tracker.css"/>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <h1>Register New User</h1>
      </div>

      @{[ @errors ? join("\n", map "<p>Error: $_</p>", @errors) : '' ]}

      <div id="content">
         <form action="register.pl" method="POST">
         <b>Name:</b> @{[ $q->textfield( -name => 'name' ) ]}<br>
         <b>UserName:</b> @{[ $q->textfield( -name => 'username' ) ]}<br>
         <b>Password:</b> @{[ $q->password_field( -name => 'password' ) ]}<br>
         <input type="submit">
      </div>
   </body>
<html>
END_PAGE

__DATA__
```